# How to disable self-defense in Kaspersky Anti-Virus 6.0?

Tags: kaspersky

I'm using my personal laptop at work, and my system administrator convinced me to install KAV 6.0 with the network agent. The problem is, he configured KAV to prompt for an admin password whenever I try to exit the application from the notification area icon context menu. I don't mind running the anti-virus during work hours, but at home it can be a serious drag on resources, to a point where I can't play some of my favorite games anymore. I've confronted the guy about this and got denied. Still, can I do something about this, seeing as I've got administrator privileges on my own laptop? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when you password protect the anti-virus's real-time monitor, this means that you need to have the username and password for the antivirus itself; having administrator privileges on the system isn't enough.

You could attempt to stop the antivirus's monitoring service (open the Run dialogue box, and type in 'services.msc'). Here, find the antivirus service and stop it.

Of course, if the antivirus works as it should, the service will either fail to stop or simply start back up again in a matter of seconds.

Your best bet is to convice your IT-guy to give you the password to the antivirus. Still, I wouldn't recommend running a computer with no antivirus protection in ANY scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The network administrator should not give you the password. What he should do is remove it from your computer. At that point, even with these enterprise level products, most of these packages have an unmanaged version they could give you to use.

In the alternative, after they remove it, just pick a different free AV to use.